# after div display set to block nothing shows

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, chart.js

I used bootstrap in my project. in each tab i show a chart my problem is the div display attribute is none and after user clicked on **a** tag the div display changes to the block. also i wrote a function to handle displaying the chart. but when user clicks on the tab chart not showing. but if i remove the display:none attribute its showing with no problem. 
this is my div :

```
<div id="bar" style="display: none">
   <?php echo chart($title,$data,'Bar');?>
</div>
```

and this is my chart function :

```
function chart($title,$data,$type){
ob_start();
?>
<script src="<?php echo url()?>/assets/chart/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo url()?>/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<canvas style="display: block;margin: 0 auto;" id="myCanvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
<script>
$(function(){
  var ctx = $('#myCanvas').get(0).getContext('2d');
  var barChartData = {
    labels : <?php echo json_encode($title) ?>,
    datasets : [
      {
        fillColor : "rgba(10, 150, 100, 0.8)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(24, 107, 2, 0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(4, 20, 60, 0.9)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(5, 35, 70, 1)",
        data : <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>
      }
    ]
  };
  var pieChart = new Chart(ctx).<?php echo $type?>(barChartData);
});
</script>
<?php
$view = ob_get_clean();
return $view;
}
```

and this is the script that shows the div when its clicked:

```
 $('#aBar').on('click',function(){
  $('#circle').css('display','none');
  $('#line').css('display','none');
  $('#bar').css('display','block');
});
```

Comment: Where is the script that displays #bar on click?

Comment: I guess whatever plugin you are using for chart, it is using container dimension while getting initialized. You should initialize plugin once element is visible or use other way to set element outside of viewport than  `display: none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I just have to set visibility to hidden and when user clicked on **a** tag set this to visible and everything is okay.